# ObjectCache with List<> slow on first call

Tags: c#, .net

I have a webapi (asp.net) where I have put a List in the ObjectCache

```
List<User>data = GetUser();
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(30);
cache.Add("userList", data, policy);
```

I retrieve the List in a class:

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>();
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
List<User> cacheList = List<User>)cache.Get("userList");

if(cacheList != null){
   userList = cacheList;
} else{
   userList = GetUserListAndCacheTheList();
}
```

When I now make any linq query on the userlist, which did get its content from the cacheList, it takes a lot of time. But only on the first time, if i call the class through the webapi url again any linq query is fast.

```
//Why 
userlist = userList.Where(user => user != null ).toList<User>();
```

It seems like something is recomputed then, but don't know what or why.... can somebody explain this behavior?

Comment: why do you need the null check here Where(user => user != null )?

Comment: just an example. ;)  It could be anything else. It always take a lot of time when userList is getting its content from cacheList for the first time...

Comment: What do you mean by "only on the first time"? If you keep the app alive, your code reassign the where filtering to the userlist ... So next time you call it it's already filtered right? That would explain to me why another call would be fast^^

Comment: I mean: after the cacheObject is new created, I call a webapi url, the content of cacheList is going to userlist. Then any linq query is going to take lot of time. If i recall the webapi url again, the content of cacheList is going to userlist again, but now the linq it is fast. On my project first call takes 40 sec, second call 200ms.